# migrate ruby on rails salted bcrypt to md5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

I'm trying to migrate a ruby on rails app to django, and got stuck with the fact that the RoR app is encrypting the user passwords in 2 feilds, crypted_password and password_salt, in addition the persistence_toke, so is there any play around to replace this with just a simple md5 hashed passwords without resetting the passwords of all users?

Comment: Why would you use MD5? Just don't do that.

Comment: Django has a bcrypt password hasher. If you can combine the two database fields into a single field that uses the same syntax as Django passwords, you might be able to use the encrypted passwords like that without any additional user interaction. Django will then automatically upgrade the password to the most secure algorithm when the user logs in.

Answer (score 1):

You need the password in plain text to store it hashed (with `MD5` or any other algorithm). That said: You would need to restore the user's password from the current bcrypted version. And to avoid the possibility of a decryption is exactly the reason why `bcrypt` exists.

Therefore that answer is: No, you cannot do that without your user's help.

Btw MD5 is considered unsecure. You should try hard to get the `bcrypt` version working with `Django`.